# HTML div vertical position issue

Tags: html, css

I need to a display div in same line with some content inside it, below is the code, it's working fine but when the text length is larger the vertical position of the last div is shifted up, I need every div aligned properly.

```
<div id="bootmPanel" style=" box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);border: 0px solid rgba(244,244,244,0.7); position: absolute;right:0; bottom: 0;display:block;background-color:rgba(52,47,52,.7);width:100%;height:200px" >


    <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="images/icon/alert.png" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>

     <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="images/icon/alert.png" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>

     <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="images/icon/alert.png" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>

     <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="images/icon/alert.png" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>



   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `float:left` to your divs.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`float:left`** in css for all the div. Also instead of inline css, you should add a class and pass all the css into that class.

Also if you don't need **position** just remove it along with right and bottom css.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the `display:inline-block; to float:left.` 
for some css basics you can try this website [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add code `float:left` as below

**CSS:**

```css
div{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="bootmPanel" style=" box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);border: 0px solid rgba(244,244,244,0.7); position: absolute;right:0; bottom: 0;display:block;background-color:rgba(52,47,52,.7);width:100%;height:200px" >


    <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>
    
     <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>
    
     <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>
    
     <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>
<div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>

   

   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this css

```
div#bootmPanel >div {
      vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the inline property `display:block` from `#bootmPanel` and use flexbox.

In fact to would be better to separate out all the CSS from HTML.

```css
#bootmPanel{
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="bootmPanel" style=" box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);border: 0px solid rgba(244,244,244,0.7); position: absolute;right:0; bottom: 0;background-color:rgba(52,47,52,.7);width:100%;height:200px" >
    <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>      
    <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:5px;width:105px;height:130px;border:1px solid rgba(244,244,244,1);margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" width=70px; height:30; alt="Alert" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;">
    <p> <span style="color:white;font-size:12px;display:block;width:95px;word-wrap:break-word;">Images can improve the design Images can improve the design </span> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```